# An annoying argument over limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I and my friend having an argument of limit, 
we are often driven into philosophical debate, which is not good, because it is not effective. therefore I need someone mastery of calculus and anaylsis to shed some light on it:

To my knowledge, 
a limit is really **NOT something**, and it is really **NOT EQUAL to something**, 
it is actually an **inequality**.

If I say 
$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}=0$

What I am really saying is 
there is a sequence $\frac{1}{N}$

If $N$ gets bigger, $\frac{1}{N}$ will get smaller, but never below zero or reach zero. (the zero works kind of a Greatest Lower Bound in this case)

while my friend insist (in our discussion of electrodynamics) that **as** $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}$ **the whole thing is something**, and **it exactly is equal to zero**.

So who win the argument?

Comment: Your friend should have won !

Comment: FYI: We can say that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\tfrac{(-1)^n}{n} = 0$ even though $0$ is neither the greatest lower bound nor the least upper bound of the sequence $\tfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Have you learned the definition of a limit yet?

Comment: Your friend is correct. You haven't understood correctly the definition of a limit, while your friend has, you should review it to clear this doubt.

Comment: well, it doesn't make sense to me in view of set theory, if I collect all the elements $N$, then none of this will lead to zero (in my example). therefore, the zero must work as a trend (or bound in my example).

Comment: I would suggest watching Vi Hart's video on [9.999... reasons that .999... = 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TINfzxSnnIE) to better understand infinity and how it is used in limits...you seem to be stuck in assuming infinity is an actual number--it's not.

Comment: and before I take limit, and after taking limit I presume the elements in my equation do not change "essentially". and hence speaking of "there is something equal to zero" in my equation is quite strange, as before taking limit, my equation works perfectly fine without zero

Comment: You wrote down an equality.  It is correct.  The object on the left is what you are discussing, and the object on the right is $0$.

Comment: I got it now, the limit is referring to the L in Epsilon-delta limit definition! too bad, I still win the debate, kind of , my friend told me that's why one of my equation goes to zero, which unfortunately is exactly riemann sum.

Comment: @ShingLau You should really check more carefully the things you write down and stop believing you won an argument you clearly lost with your friend: the limit is referring **exactly** tho what it is, and which you *still* haven't understood, and not to any epsilon-delta nonsense and etc., which refers to limits **of functions**. And there is no Riemann sum *at all* around this matter. Go back to your books and try to understand this to depth. And by the way, you **also** have no equations here! You have an equality, which can be true or false (and it is true), no equations at all.

Comment: you serious? There is NO limits in Riemann sum?

Comment: @ShingLau There is no Riemann sum **in this**! Again, read c-a-r-e-f-u-l-l-y.

Comment: well, forgive me for being not a english native speaker, by equation, I mean math.

Comment: @ShingLau english is not my mother tongue, either...and that still another reason to be more careful when arguing about these matters.

Comment: well, pardon me, I didn't know the definition in sequence doesn't share the same name as function's. and it seems to have no name at all.

Comment: @ShingLau This has nothing to do with a limit of a sequence vs. a function--it can _both_ be understood as a limit of a sequence _and_ as a limit of a function, i.e. the function: $\mathbb{R}\backslash 0 \mapsto \mathbb{R}: f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ where we take the limit that $x \rightarrow \pm\infty$.

Comment: I have written my answer in order to check if I understand this matter, please feel free to read it and comment if I hopelessly get it wrong again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}=0$.

You are right in a way that as $N\to \infty, \hspace{2pt} \frac{1}{N}\to 0$ and never actually hits $0$ but the **limit** of the sequence is **equal** to $0$.
Limit is a a g.l.b or l.u.b if we are dealing with bounded monotone sequences, but does not have to be always as suggested in comments.

Saying that the sequence {$a_n$} approaches $L$ as $n\to \infty$ is same as $\lim_{N\to\infty} \{{a_n}\}=L$.

Comment: oh right! the limit is referred to that particular number L in that Epsilon-delta limit definition. Thanks.

Comment: @yes. In case of limits  Always go with the epsilon-delta definition.

Comment: @ShingLau There is NO epsilon-delta here, at most it is epsilon-M.

Comment: I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit

Comment: well, both definitions share the same idea, that's what I was referring to. I do not know what upset you guys. Sorry, I have a bad memories for names.

Comment: yes thats what I was saying Shing, epsilon-delta , or epsilon-M are same things it is just a standard name for this definition to say it epsilon-delta. No one is upset here.

Answer (score 1):

You can understand the $\lim$ operator as a functional that associates a number $L$ to a sequence $f_n$.

$$\mathbb N\mapsto\mathbb R,f\mapsto\lim_{x\to\infty}f_n=L.$$

Similarly, for functions of the continuous variable, specifying the evaluation point in $\bar{\mathbb R}$:

$$(\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R)\times\bar{\mathbb R},(f,a)\mapsto\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L.$$

The limit is just a number and you can use it as such, for example to express continuity

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a).$$

Comment: Thanks! You answer exactly what I asked for, and I like it, but I am not quite familiar with functional, anyway, so far I will just treat it as "approximations"  in my physics work(my major)

Answer (score 0):

Consider a real–valued sequence
$$\Bbb N \ni n\mapsto \frac {\sin(n\pi/100)}n$$

- Zero is neither the upper nor the lower bound of the sequence values.
- Some sequence terms are equal $0$ (and there are infinitely many such zero terms), however the sequence does not stay there — there are always further terms, which are *not* zero.
- Anyway, as $n$ grows, sequence terms get closer and closer to zero — for any, arbitrarily tiny range centered at zero, there is such index $M\in\Bbb N$ that all terms past the $M$-th one belong to that range.

So the limit **exists** and it **is** zero:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {\sin(n\pi/100)}n = 0$$

---

On the other hand, a constant sequence $$n\mapsto 1$$ that is a sequence $1, 1, 1, 1, 1\ldots$ does not *tend* anywhere, anyway it also has a limit, namely number one: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}1 = 1$$